# How to watch variable in service from controller within AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

I'm writing app functionality, that set loading gif when request are executing (in learning purposes). I use AngularJS 1.4.5, "Controller as" syntax and John Papa style guides.
So, I wrote an *interceptor* that pass quantity of current request to service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('eventApp')
        .factory('requestInterceptorService', requestInterceptorService);

    requestInterceptorService.$inject = ['$q', 'loadingService'];

    function requestInterceptorService($q, loadingService) {

        var numLoadings = 0; 
        var requestInterceptorServiceFactory = {
            request: request,
            response: response,
            responseError: responseError
        };
        return requestInterceptorServiceFactory;

        function request(config) {
            numLoadings++;
            loadingService.setLoaderStatus(numLoadings);
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
        function response(response) {
            numLoadings--;
            loadingService.setLoaderStatus(numLoadings);
            return response || $q.when(response);

        }
        function responseError(response) {
            numLoadings--;
            loadingService.setLoaderStatus(numLoadings);
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
})();
```

This is my *loading.service* with flag *isLoadgerEnabled*, that indicate whether we need to show loading image or not:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('eventApp')
        .factory('loadingService', loadingService);

    function loadingService() {

        var isLoaderEnabled = false;

        var loadingServiceFactory = {
            setLoaderStatus: setLoaderStatus,
            getLoaderStatus: getLoaderStatus,
            isLoaderEnabled: isLoaderEnabled
        };

        return loadingServiceFactory;

        function setLoaderStatus(numberOfRequests) {
            var status = false;
            if (numberOfRequests === 0) {
                status = false;
            }
            if (numberOfRequests !== 0) {
                status = true;
            }
            isLoaderEnabled = status;
        }

        function getLoaderStatus() {
            return isLoaderEnabled;
        }
    }
})();
```

Above code works for me. 
On view I have *div* with loading image and *ng-show directive*, that listens flag from *index controller:*

```
<div id="loaderDiv">
   <img src="client/assets/img/loader.gif" class="content-loader" 
        ng-show="index.isLoaderEnabled" />
</div> 

.controller('indexController', indexController);

    indexController.$inject = ['$location', 'authService', 'authModal', 'loadingService', '$scope'];

    function indexController($location, authService, authModal, loadingService, $scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.isLoaderEnabled = loadingService.isLoaderEnabled;
        //code with other functionality 

        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return loadingService.isLoaderEnabled;
        }, function (newValue) {
            vm.isLoaderEnabled = newValue;
        });
    }
})();
```

My problem: vm.isLoaderEnabled *isn't updating with service* (actually vm.isLoaderEnabled always false) and I'm not sure where is problem.
I would like to write efficient and elegant solution for this functionality, maybe without $scope (if it's possible).
I'm ready for questions, refactoring advice or better ideas to bind data to view.

Comment: you can expose the `loadingService` on your vm object and then in your html do ng-show="index.loadingService.isLoaderEnabled"

Comment: @JoseM Sadly, that didn't help. isLoaderEnabled (in controller) is initialized just once and that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution for my problem. 
At first I want to point at that part of code in loadingService:

```
var loadingServiceFactory = {
            setLoaderStatus: setLoaderStatus,
            getLoaderStatus: getLoaderStatus,
            isLoaderEnabled: isLoaderEnabled//<------1 line
        };

        return loadingServiceFactory;//<------2 line
```

In the *1 line* I **copy** isLoaderEnabled to property isLoaderEnabled, and on *2 line* I return it. So loadingController gets **copy** of my loading flag. If I only found that earlier my code could work (because I tried many other solutions).

So, solution. I work out that using Observer pattern: that is not very good practice in Angular, but it works (anyway I will overwrite my code in future).

1. requestInterceptor - didn't change
2. loading service:

   ```
      (function () {
   'use strict';
   angular
       .module('eventApp')
       .factory('loadingService', loadingService);

   function loadingService() {

       var isLoaderEnabled = false;
       var callbacks = [];
       var loadingServiceFactory = {
           setLoaderStatus: setLoaderStatus,
           getLoaderStatus: getLoaderStatus,
           register: register
       };

       return loadingServiceFactory;

       function setLoaderStatus(numberOfRequests) {
           if (numberOfRequests === 0) {
               isLoaderEnabled = false;
           }
           if (numberOfRequests > 0) {
               isLoaderEnabled = true;
           }
           notify();
       }

       function getLoaderStatus() {
           return isLoaderEnabled;
       }

       function register(callback) {
           callbacks.push(callback);
       }

       function notify() {
           callbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
               callback();
           });
       }
   }
      })();
   ```
3. loading controller:

   ```
   (function () {
   'use strict';
   angular
       .module('eventApp')
       .controller('indexController', indexController);

   indexController.$inject = ['$location', 'authService', 'authModal', 'loadingService'];

   function indexController($location, authService, authModal, loadingService) {
       /* jshint validthis: true*/
       var vm = this;
       vm.loading = false;            

       vm.loaderObserver = function () {
           vm.loading = loadingService.getLoaderStatus();
       }

       loadingService.register(vm.loaderObserver);

       //other unnecessary code
   };
   })();
   ```
4. Loader div

   ```
       <div id="loaderDiv" ng-show="index.loading" >
                       <img src="client/assets/img/loader.gif" class="content-loader" />
                </div>
   ```

I hope this will help someone.